# C# timeout on tcpstream.read

Tags: c#

I have the following code to read and write to a HTTP stream, however I'm dealing with iffy servers so I would like to be have a timeout on my read operation as well. I just don't know how to put it together in a nice manner

```
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        Task write = stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        int i = 0;
        Boolean finished = false;
        while (!finished)
        {
            while (stream.DataAvailable)
            {
                i += stream.Read(buffer_, i, 1024);

                if (i > 3)
                {
                    if (buffer_[i - 1] == 0x00)
                    {
                        finished = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (!write.Wait(1000))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("write timed out");
            return null;
        }
        return buffer_.Take(i).ToArray();
```

Comment: @Eser I tested in python with the request module, works fine with a timeout but I'm not sure what that timeout actually does in code

Comment: Remove *while (stream.DataAvailable)* the and use `stream.ReadTimeout`.

Comment: @Eser that fixed it, don't totally understand why that didn't work though